# Show particular system process name on java Swing GUI List

Tags: java, swing, jnienv

I have a list of system processes given by following method:
    public native int fetchProcessIDs(int[] pids);
    public native String getProcessName(int hProcess);
    I have to show these processes on java swing  GUI list.But I want to show only particular          processes on that GUI list. e.g I want to show only the system process with name chrome.exe on        the gui List.And the process and memory status also shown on the gui.
    How can I show the particular process on list out of given native method list.
    Please suggest some solution Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)? What have you [tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: No...it is JList.It is like jsysmonitor system tool..

Comment: `JTable` has filtering built in, other wise you will need to build you own `ListModel` either containing the already filtered list or with filter capabilities